Defining subharmonic function on a manifold
Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $\pi:\bar{M}\rightarrow M$ be the universal covering space. Suppose we have a smooth subharmonic function $f:\bar{M}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then we want to define a nonconstant subharmonic function on $M$ using the mapping $\pi$. Actually, we want to push the subharmonic function $f$ from $\bar{M}$ to $M$. We have tried to define a function $g$ on $M$ as follows: $$g(x)=\sum_{y\in \pi^{-1}(x)}f(y), \text{ for }x\in M.$$ This definition works only when the fundamental group of $M$ is finite; otherwise, it needs to prove the convergence of the right-hand side.
Please help me in proving the convergence of the above right-hand side series.
